# haskell understanding fmap

Tags: haskell, recursion, tree

Could somebody help or give some direction of how I can understand the fmap function in following implementation.

```
data Rose a = a :> [Rose a] deriving (Eq, Show)
instance Functor Rose where
fmap f (x :> xs) = (f x) :> fmap (fmap f) xs

tree :: Rose Int
tree = 1 :> [2:>[]]
```

The part which I don't understand the (fmap f), why does it again go in recursion, but it only takes 1 parameter. How is this possible, because it needs to 2.

The second part is that I don't undestand why this not works:

```
fmap f (x :> xs) = (f x) :> fmap f xs
```

I hope that someone could give me some direction of how understand this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because `xs` is a list of `Rose a`.

Perhaps this is clearer:

```
fmap f (x :> xs) = (f x) :> map (fmap f) xs
                            ^^^
```

Of course, for lists, `map` = `fmap`.

That is:

1. apply `f` to `x`.
2. for `xs`, map the function `fmap f` over the list `xs`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I finally undestand it.:D

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to currying!!  What is happening is that you are 'partially applying' the inner fmap to get a function that you feed to outer fmap.  It is only this nested `fmap` that can get through both the `Rosetree` and the `[]` containers.

Note that

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> h a -> h b
```

So partially applied like below gives a function

```
let g = fmap f :: h a -> hb
```

It is this function that is then fed to the other fmap

```
fmap g xs
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It really helped me to understand!